# Update failed on Metadata module, any easy fix?

Tags: updating, wsod

I am very sorry to bring a rather nebulous question here but need any and all help I can get:  for the first time, I've had a "White Screen of Death" issue when trying to update a module.  I believe it was the "Metadata" module but I don't even remember for sure.  I had a previous backup of the database and site files/folders from a day ago, so I didn't make one this time.  Followed the Drupal tool for downloading, installing, and...presto....White Screen of Death.

Trying not to panic, I reverted to the older backup.  Which I hoped would solve the issue.

Yet it did not.

So my question is whether perhaps (fingers crossed!) there's additional steps I need to take once a backup is in place to get things working again.  I tried truncating every "cache_..." line via PhpMyAdmin, but it didn't help.  I tried the "update.php" in the URL hoping it was (maybe) just an index.php issue.  Again...no dice.

I've seen a long page about WSOD possible issues but don't want to just muddle around doing that if I don't know what I'm doing, which I don't.

Are there any suggestions for quick, simple things I've either forgotten or could try to get this working again?  And if I can't, can I manually copy files and folders over somehow and try again?

Thank you all in advance for any help.  I really appreciate it.  Stay healthy out there!

Comment: When you restore the DB and the `sites/files` folder, this does not restore your old code base. You also need to restore to the old code base / module versions to turn your backup into a running site.

Comment: Hi Hudri.  

I replaced (via my ISP) the entire root directory and all subfolders, and the database.  I didn't just swap out the sites/files.  (Though maybe I should double check that they recursively backed up the folder...if they only did the top root directory that would definitely explain things!)  Thank you!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

So the solution here was that the backup (done by my ISP) did not fully restore.  I think they forgot to recursively restore and just did the main Drupal root.  Once I asked them if they were sure they restored recursively and there was a long pause (a few hours, at which point the site started working again) they came back and said they'd missed a few files.

So luckily that solved it.  I did not need to configure anything or run any update.php or such.  Just restored the entire Drupal directory and all subdirs and such, and a database restore to match.  That fixed it.  Whew!